# Access Activity File in Manisfest file

Tags: android, xml, model-view-controller, android-manifest, filepath

I'm trying to use the MVC architecture in challenge to build a pokedex.

I'm having problems in access the activities inside the packages that I created in the manifest file.

Above the manifest and activities files.

Someone could tell me **what's wrong with the path of the activity file**?

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.pokemon">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_splash_screen_pokemon_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name="com.pokemon.View.SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.pokemon.View.MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.pokemon.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.pokemon.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.pokemon.View;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.pokemon.R;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    /* Timer Splash Screen */
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            /* THis method will run right after the execution of the splash finish */
            @Override
            public void run()
            {   /* The Main Activity will be started */
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

**Files Structure in the project**

[image]

Comment: clean build, invalidate the cache and restart..

Comment: make sure the package name is correct

Comment: Post your Activities (including package declaration).

Comment: I already made the clean build and invalidate the cache and restart. I edited the post with the activities code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the packages names. I renamed some packages and apparently the Android Studio wasn't identifying and executing the app in the right way.

I solved the problem creating the project again with the names of the packages that I refactored in the previous project.